# How to reach parameters of method in global error handling in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, global-asax

I am newbie to error handling in global.asax in asp.net mvc5.In Application_Error i can reach all url but is there any way to see Post parameters of method in global.asax to give the meaning the error.
In detail i have Application_Error() as below.

```
protected void Application_Error()
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('_')[1]);
        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            RequestContext requestContext = ((MvcHandler)httpContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;

            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {


                httpContext.Response.Clear();
                string controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
                IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
                IController controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
                ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, (ControllerBase)controller);
                JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
                jsonResult.Data = new { Success = false, Message = "Error" };
                jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                jsonResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
                httpContext.Response.End();
            }

        }
    }
```

What if you take an error in Method like below

```
  public JsonResult(ExampleModel example){
    return Json("");}
```

Is there any way to reach the properties of ExampleModel class in Application_Error()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an out of the box way to get the whole `ExampleModel` object in global.asax, but for sure you can access individual request parameters that this object consists of. Say if the model has property `ExampleProperty` which was posted with request, this should give you its value:

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Current.Request["ExampleProperty"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer its getting specific property of model class

Comment: @mayk, yup. To get the whole object you may need to do the model binding manually. In a normal flow of things this is what ASP.NET MVC pipeline is doing for you while calling action method.

Comment: Yep, Thans again. You are right specific property check is better for all.